# Custom Campaign Receiver shows only first parameter of referrer

Tags: android

I implemented my own BroadCastReceiver for com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER.
In my receiver i wrote this line of code:

```
String ref = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
Log.d(TAG, "REF: "+ ref);
```

When i make a testcall:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n mypackage/.helper.InstallReceiver --es  "referrer" "utm_medium=test_medium&utm_term=test_term&utm_content=test_content&utm_campaign=test_name"
```

i see in the LogCat just:

```
REF: utm_medium=test_medium
```

The other parameters are missing.

Comment: try to encode utf8 your referrer. Or you can use URL builder on [Google Analytic](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/campaigns#google-play-url-builder) Copy those encoded string and use adb command. I had this issue too